# Why does one count mississippily?

Tags: meaning

I was watching an [episode](https://youtu.be/hc1C0I6x3lI?t=260) of *Friends* where Ross talks about "counting mississippily".

I did not get the joke. Why would someone say "Mississippi" after every number? Is there some story behind it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the dots are part of the punctuation of the name, and are rather just a decoration in the logo.

Comment: Great question; too bad none of the answers have any clues to the origin though. There must be countless words which can approximate one second, so why the name of a southern US state?

Comment: @tenfour: I did not think of that, neither do I know 'why missipy and not some other word'. Maybe you can ask that question and see if someone here knows..

Comment: The name of that particular state is used just because it's a peculiar word, with perfectly lined-up, same-vowel syllables. Which sounds kind of funny, if you think about it, and is therefore a mnemonic device hard to forget. South has nothing at all to do with it. It's a school-kiddy thingamajig. You know, when they start to learn all the states. That adults use it too, proves that kids too sway some influence on the language.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Mississippi* is one of several phrases used to approximate one second for the purposes of informal time keeping.  That is, if you count to five "Mississippily", then you've counted five seconds.  Outside North America, as you might image, this is usually not very common.

In English, I've heard several different methods of doing this.  E.g.

- *Elephant* i.e. "one-elephant, two-elephant", etc.
- Postfixing 1000 to the number, i.e. "1-1000, 2-1000", etc.
- Adding 1000 to the number, i.e. "1001, 1002", etc.

In other languages, they have similar constructs, but adjust for appropriate time.  For example, in some German speaking areas, they just say "einundzwanzig" (German for 21) over and over.  I find this one particularly interesting because they don't actually include the current count in the number, but rather must keep it in their head.  I've heard of a variation where they start at 21 and go up.  I'm not sure what happens when they hit 30, since it has substantially fewer syllables than 29.

Comment: Over here (Israel) we use count `twenty-one, twenty-two` or `Esrim Ve'Achat, Esrim Ve'Shtaim` to estimate proper distance between yo and the car in front of you while driving

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard a German saying *einundzwanzig* over and over again. Every German I know counts *einundzwanzig*, *zweiundzwanzig*, *dreiundzwanzig*. The idea is that 4 syllables = roughly 1 second. *Dreißig* is a bit of a bummer, because it has only two syllables, but it gets counterbalanced by *siebenunddreißig*, which has five. Same for *vierzig/siebenundvierzig*, *fünfzig/siebenundfünfzig*, and so forth. Also, it is not uncommon in German to count Mississippis (*ein Mississippi*, *zwei Mississippis*...), though counting from 21 up is certainly more popular.

Comment: @RegDwight: If you count from _ein Mississippi_, what happens if you reach _einundzwanzig Mississippis_?! :)

Comment: I was told 'kodak' in my day....

Comment: The Danes count crates of beer (_en kasse øl, to kasser øl, tre kasser øl_, etc.), but the use is a bit more limited in English: it is only used when trying to figure out approximately how far away from you a lightning struck. For counting seconds in general, I think most people would just count regularly, but more slowly.

Comment: Yup. In my driver's ed class, when we were instructed to keep the safe, two-second distance from the car in front, we were taught to count: "One-one-thousand, two-one-thousand." My friend preferred "one-Mississippi, two-Mississippi."

Comment: My dad taught me "cat-and-dog." I was quite surprised when I later discovered that I was apparently the only person in existence to use this particular phrase.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I think many will say _Dreißig_ at the same length as the other numbers, i.e. keep the rythm, "neunundzwanzig, drei-ßig; einunddreißig, ..." as |  |.

Comment: I was taught to count hippopotomusly. Googling, other people do it, too, but it's a lot less common than counting Mississippily.

Comment: In my family we count by Africa-1, africa-2, africa-3 and so on. It has the advantage over 1-Mississippi, 1-elephant and similar counting methods that the 'one' doesn't occur until the first second has actually elapsed.

Comment: Czechs do the same thing as Germans counting 21, 22: jednadvacet, dvaadvacet, třiadvacet... and like Danes, we also use it mostly to estimate the distance of a lightning strike.

Answer (score 7):

People count "1-Mississippi, 2-Mississippi" because that way your count includes the approximate seconds so that you can space out the numbers better. Otherwise you might count 1, 2, 3 too fast.

Answer (score 6):

Very good question!  I've always assumed that it was for the purposes of spacing out numbers while playing hide-and-seek.  If you don't ensure that the numbers are a good distance apart, then obviously the seeker just burbles "onetwothreefourfivesixseveneightninetennnnnnnnahundred... ready or not, here I come"!

Comment: For us it used to be "One, two, miss-a-few, ninety-nine, A HUNDRED!"

Comment: Sort of bad form to begin your answer with "I don't know..."

Comment: @Chris Dwyer: what, you'd rather people didn't disclose when they were making an educated guess instead of being 100% absolutely certain of their answer?  I'm just trying to build a world where honesty isn't a dirty word.  Since (it seems that) my answer was neither misleading nor wrong, I don't really understand the problem you're having.

Comment: @thesunneversets I agree with Chris on this. This is the place to post answers, not your assumptions. I think it would've been better if you would've posted this as a comment to the question

Comment: @Chris, @JohnoBoy: fair enough guys!  I come from a culture where if you can make a pretty good, evidentially-based guess at an answer it's considered a worthwhile contribution to a debate (or at least not a serious offence).  I couldn't find any hard-and-fast rules in the FAQ about how sure you have to be of your answers, but since it's at least two against one now I'll make sure not to submit mere educated guesses as answers in future :)

Comment: Perhaps, "I don't know" could been better phrased as "I'm not certain, but..", but I'm with thesunnerversets on this. We need more people offering their best answer with humility, and a lot less people so utterly convinced that *their* answer is irrefutable. If only 'correct' answers are required, why do we allow more that one answer per question?

Answer (score 0):

The only time we ever used this to count was in touch football, as there being so many "Mississippi's before the defender(s) could charge the QB.

Try as one might, saying "one-Mississippi" faster than about a second is nigh impossible.